# Search Bar searching multiple excel sheets macro

Tags: excel, search, vba

I have created a search table that will look at two separate sheets to find a specific value.  This was working before but now it will only search the dsheet and not the gsheet.  Any advice will be greatly appreciated. I have added stars to the spot that cause the issue. I have defined my strings, integers, and worksheets.

```
dsheet.Select
finalrow = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



For i = 1 To finalrow
If IIf(change <> "", Cells(i, 1) = change, True) And IIf(process <> "", Cells(i, 2) = process, True) And IIf(customer <> "", Cells(i, 3) = customer, True) And IIf(material <> "", Cells(i, 4) = material, True) And IIf(number <> "", Cells(i, 5) = number, True) And IIf(vstream <> "", Cells(i, 6) = vstream, True) And IIf(words <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 7), words) > 0, True) And IIf(lessons <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 8), lessons) > 0, True) And IIf(dday <> "", Cells(i, 10) = dday, True) And IIf(manager <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 9), manager) > 0, True) Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)).Copy
ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 10).Value = dsheet.Range(dsheet.Cells(i, 1), dsheet.Cells(i, 10)).Value


dsheet.Select

End If

**Next i


gsheet.Select
finalrow2 = gsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To finalrow
If IIf(change <> "", Cells(j, 1) = change, True) And IIf(process <> "", Cells(j, 2) = process, True) And IIf(customer <> "", Cells(j, 3) = customer, True) And IIf(material <> "", Cells(j, 4) = material, True) And IIf(number <> "", Cells(j, 5) = number, True) And IIf(vstream <> "", Cells(j, 6) = vstream, True) And IIf(words <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 7), words) > 0, True) And IIf(lessons <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 8), lessons) > 0, True) And IIf(dday <> "", Cells(j, 10) = dday, True) And IIf(manager <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 9), manager) > 0, True) Then
Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 10)).Copy
ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 10).Value = gsheet.Range(gsheet.Cells(j, 1), gsheet.Cells(j, 10)).Value


gsheet.Select

End If

Next j**

ssheet.Select
Range("B3").Select


With ssheet
    .Protect Password:="QA190", AllowFiltering:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You have some naked ranges!  See how you have `ssheet.Range()` in some places? You must do that with `Cells()` also. Just leaving `Range()` and `Cells()` without a qualifier, it's going to run that on the `ActiveSheet`, whatever that may be.  So, add the sheet reference before each instance of `Range()` and `Cells()` (even when `Cells()` is in `Range()`).

Comment: Okay so how do i fix it?

Comment: As Bruce said: use `ssheet.Range`, `dsheet.Range`, `ssheet.Cells` or `dsheet.Cells` everywhere as applicable.

Comment: Im sorry but i still dont understand.  Every single one is counted for besides (change <> "", Cells(j, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. As per comments above, plus have removed Selects which are unnecessary and slow down code.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, finalrow As Long, finalrow2 As Long

finalrow = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To finalrow
    If IIf(Change <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 1) = Change, True) And IIf(process <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 2) = process, True) And IIf(customer <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 3) = customer, True) And IIf(material <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 4) = material, True) And IIf(Number <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 5) = Number, True) And IIf(vstream <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 6) = vstream, True) And IIf(Words <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 7), Words) > 0, True) And IIf(lessons <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 8), lessons) > 0, True) And IIf(dday <> "", dsheet.Cells(i, 10) = dday, True) And IIf(manager <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 9), manager) > 0, True) Then
        ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 10).Value = dsheet.Range(dsheet.Cells(i, 1), dsheet.Cells(i, 10)).Value
    End If
Next i

finalrow2 = gsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 1 To finalrow2
    If IIf(Change <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 1) = Change, True) And IIf(process <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 2) = process, True) And IIf(customer <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 3) = customer, True) And IIf(material <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 4) = material, True) And IIf(Number <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 5) = Number, True) And IIf(vstream <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 6) = vstream, True) And IIf(Words <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 7), Words) > 0, True) And IIf(lessons <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 8), lessons) > 0, True) And IIf(dday <> "", gsheet.Cells(j, 10) = dday, True) And IIf(manager <> "", InStr(gsheet.Cells(j, 9), manager) > 0, True) Then
        ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 10).Value = gsheet.Range(gsheet.Cells(j, 1), gsheet.Cells(j, 10)).Value
    End If
Next j

With ssheet
    .Protect Password:="QA190", AllowFiltering:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, that helped but it still not showing all the values that are on the two sheets.

Comment: There was a small typo in the second loop - try it now. Both loops used the same end point. Also I have only just noticed that I think the two Copy lines are redundant.

Comment: Still not working....it wont find anything on gsheet still for certain criteria    UPDATE: i had to have the gsheet.select otherwise it doesnt work.

Comment: Try it now. Hadn't realised your code went off the page. If the same problem persists hopefully you get the idea and can correct it.